# Howto publish a git repository with ruby as zipfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitolite

I am using **OpenProject** as project management software and I am not very familiar with ruby and rails, but using the gitolite-plugin works quite well.

I am looking for a solution to provide a link to the OpenProject users where they can directly **download** the gitolite-hosted **repository as a zipfile**.

Is that possible ?

I am willing to put pieces of code together, so even partially solutions and hints are welcome.
thx.

Comment: Why not host it on sourceforge or something

Comment: 'git achieve' command will export project files into a zip file.

Comment: Do you need a repository, with entire history, or just a snapshot of the source tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in [`oliverguenther/openproject-revisions_git`](https://github.com/oliverguenther/openproject-revisions_git) would do a :

- [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) (full repo history in one file)
- [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) (latest working tree as one zip file)

You would need to extend that plugin in order to expose that feature, implementing a ruby function to call git-archive on the right project, a [bit like in this gist](https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/476428#file-gitextractor-rb-L39-L54):

(extract)

```rb
  # Runs the `git archive` command to pull your repository out 
  # into a tar or tar.gz and writes it to a temporary directory
  #
  # Args:
  # * path - path within the repository to archive, defaults to the root
  #
  # Returns the path to the tar file
  def archive(path=nil)
    @archive_path = path || ''
    create_tmp_directory
    @tar_path = "#{@tmp_directory_path}/archive.tar#{@gzip}"
    Dir.chdir @path
    puts "Archived repository" if run_shell_cmd "git archive --prefix=#{@archive_path}/ #{@branch}:#{@archive_path} -o #{@tar_path}" and @verbose
    Dir.chdir @pwd
    @tar_path
end
```